# How LINQ returns IEnumerable<T> if interface cannot be instantiated?

Tags: c#, linq, interface, instantiation

I have the following method:

```
   public IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> products, ISpecification<T> specification)
    {
        return products.Where(specification.IsFulfilled);

    }
```

Everything works fine, but after writing this method I started to wonder - how does LINQ return IEnumerable if interfaces cannot be instantiated? Would I be able to return this IEnumerable in another way? Probably I could use foreach and yield, but again I don't understand why I am able to return IEnumerable this way.
What am I missing?

Comment: I kindly suggest you this [lecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/). After reading it I am sure you will understand the whole stuff

Comment: Also, call GetType on the result to see what type actually gets returned and you will see it’s not an interface.

Comment: @taquion Article is nice, I read it long time ago already, it doesn't really answer my question. But answers below do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a reference to an interface and have variables of the interface since somewhere there is going to be a class that implements the interface. LINQ will return an internal class that implements `IEnumerable` you will just never know what it is, not should you.

Answer (score 3):

The basic question here is "how can I return interfaces when they cannot be instantiated?", well of course you can:

```
public IFruit GetProduce()
{
    return new Apple();
}
```

This is essentially the same thing: you don't have to instantiate the interface, you can return something that implements it.

Specifically for `IEnumerable<T>`, as you've mentioned, [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) is also an option.